no sound from internal speakers (hp x360 envy) in pop os 22.04
headphones (with jack) are working well, microphone is also working well, just internal speakers are not working well. I have used some apps like pulseaudio volume control where it shows the moment in the sound bar, but I am not getting any sound output.
I tried with alsamixer, auto-mute is disabled.
I tried commands from internet like reinstall pipewire and rebooting the laptop nothing worked.
my speakers are working well in windows. I dual booted it with pop os version 22.04. it has pipewire for sound purposes.


if any extra information is needed for solving the issue please inform me

Try kernel 6.9.3.

where can we get the kernel 6.9.3 actually i tried synaptic package manager i didnt that version. I am very new to kernals. please explain me how to install it (the commands or the steps)

For starters you've installed a 2 years old distro. I would start by installing the current release, 24.04, and troubleshoot from there.
